# Processing multiple Stripe payments simultaneously in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

My Rails project is processing multiple transactions at once through Stripe. I run this code with about 1000 orders and it takes about 3-4 minutes.  Is there a way to run them all at once?

```
    Order.each do |order|
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => 2000,
        :currency => "usd",
        :customer => order.customer,
        :card => order.card
      )
    end
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Your question is premature. Instead of asking us how to do it, you're supposed to try, (and try and try) and then ask a question about a specific problem you're having with your code. Without that you're asking us to write a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to process multiple charges simultaneously (i.e., in a 'list') through the Stripe API; you need to do them one at a time.

You could speed this up by making multiple requests concurrently though, but don't make too many or you'll hit the rate limits.